# IOS: manage some viewcontroller and exit from all one time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have this code:

```
    appDelegate.firstViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstviewcontroller"];
    appDelegate.secondviewcontroller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondviewcontroller"];
    appDelegate.thirdViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdviewcontroller"];
    appDelegate.fourthviewcontroller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"fourthviewcontroller"];

    [self presentViewController:appDelegate.firstViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now in this way I allocated these viewcontrollers and I opened the firstviewcontroller with a modal mode with 'presentViewController'.
OK, when I open firstviewcontroller I want manage all other viewcontroller inside it.
In firstviewcontroller I have four button to pass at second or at third or at fourth, in the secondviewcontroller the same thing, I have four button to switch to first, third or fourth ecc...

To switch to one viewcontroller to another what instruction I should use?
And If I want to exit from all? I just call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

???

thanks

Comment: maybe you should use a tabbarcontroller ;-)

Comment: yes...it seems a tabbarcontroller but I don't want it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use container view controller to do this. You can create a new and custom one or subclass `UINavigationController` or use it as is. That way you can keep all those VCs alive and provide transitions between them by accessing them with `viewControllers` method.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926). You can look at Implementing a Container View Controller section.

You should definitely look at [that page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6).

Comment: Can I use an expression of type: [self.view addSubview:appDelegate.secondviewcontroller.view]; when I call a viewcontroller I remove the last with removefromsuperview, what do you think?

Comment: Aim of container view controller is managing all VC in its stack from the same object, in this case it would be better you access those VC by accessing "[container childViewController];". You can find many good examples of container view controllers. To make it more clear, UINavigationController is a container view controller which has child view controllers. Using appDelegate might not be a good idea.

Comment: I use appDelegate for controllers because I need that a view controller store its current state...

Comment: If you set your custom container view controller instance as root view controller of your window and add the other view controllers as child view controllers to that instance, they will store their current state. After that point, all of your VCs are alive, but only one of them is seen by the user while the others are waiting at the background. Transitioning will be handled by your custom container view controller, you can learn how to do it by looking at the links provided in my answer. When going to VC2 from VC1, remove view of VC1 and add VC2's view as subview, that's all.